# how to disable next button when it is the last image in colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I want to be able to disable(not clickable) "Next" button when it is showing the last image in colorbox so that it won't go back to the first image.

Same thing for "Previous" button.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your colorbox settings set `loop` to `false`

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox check the loop feature on this page.